# updatelayeredwindow not working

Tags: c++, png, gdi

i tried to use UpdateLayeredWindow for all day, but it failed to work :(, i put the code in OnCreate and load a png file (created by photoshop) with CImage.

```
int CMainWindow::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);
    SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 0);
    SetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(this->m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    this->SetMenu(NULL);
    ::SetWindowPos(this->m_hWnd, HWND_TOP, 50, 50, 652, 492, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    CBitmap imageBitmap, *oldBitmap;
    CDC *dcWindow, dcMem;
    CRect wRect;
    CPoint wPos;
    CSize wSize;
    HBITMAP hbmp;
    BLENDFUNCTION bFunc;

    m_Image.Load(_T("Img/BG_Blue.png"));
    GetWindowRect(&wRect);
    dcWindow = GetWindowDC();
    imageBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcWindow, wRect.Width(), wRect.Height());
    dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(dcWindow);
    oldBitmap = dcMem.SelectObject(&imageBitmap);
    m_Image.Draw(dcMem.m_hDC, 0, 0, wRect.Width(), wRect.Height(), 0, 0, wRect.Width(), wRect.Height());
    wPos.x = 0; wPos.y = 0;
    wSize.cx = wRect.left; wSize.cy = wRect.bottom;
    bFunc.SourceConstantAlpha = 125;
    bFunc.BlendFlags = 0;
    bFunc.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bFunc.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
    UpdateLayeredWindow(dcWindow, &wPos, &wSize, &dcMem, &wPos, 0, &bFunc, ULW_ALPHA);
    //BitBlt(dcWindow->m_hDC, 0, 0, wRect.Width(), wRect.Height(), dcMem.m_hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    dcMem.SelectObject(oldBitmap);
    return 0;
}
```

the function returned with 1 , but nothing appeared on the screen, only an icon on the starup menu indicating the program is running. I am wondering if there is something wrong with the png file ... can anyone help ?

Comment: Delete the first two `SetWindowLong`. Call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` after enabling `WS_EX_LAYERED`. Check MSDN for `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` usage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I know SetLayeredWindoAttributes and it works well in this program. But here i want to do some perpixel alpha manipulation which can only be done by using UpdateLayeredWindow

Comment: Don't draw anything in the OnCreate() method.  The window isn't visible yet.  Draw in OnPaint() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`dcWindow` should be the Device Context of the screen not the window. So initialize it like so: `dcWindow->Attach(::GetDC(NULL))` instead of `dcWindow = GetWindowDC();`